# Retornar Json desde un servicio a un controlador sin diagonales inversas en C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-5.0

Tengo una API web RESTful con Net 5 y EntityFrameworkCore. Estoy intentando retornar un objeto Json, pero lo que realmente estoy retornando es un string con diagonales inversas.

Al verificar el Json antes de ser retornado del servicio al controlador veo que está bien, pero al obtener el valor ya en el controlador, el formato es incorrecto.

El servicio donde obtengo el json es:

```
public async Task<string> Agrupaciones(string token)
{
    var data = await _repositorio.Agrupaciones.GetAgrupaciones();

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Agrupacion>>(json);

    var Agrupaciones = obj.GroupBy(item => new { item.IdCliente, item.Cliente },
    (key, group) => new
        {
        Cliente = key.IdCliente,
        IdCliente = key.Cliente,
        Grupos = group.GroupBy(item2 => new { item2.IdGrupo, item2.Grupo },
                (key2, group2) => new
                {
                    IdGrupo = key2.IdGrupo,
                    Grupo = key2.Grupo,
                    Subgrupos = group2.GroupBy(item3 => new { item3.IdSubgrupo, item3.Subgrupo 
                },
                                (key3, group3) => new
                                {
                                    IdSubgrupo = key3.IdSubgrupo,
                                    Subgrupo = key3.Subgrupo
                                })
                })
    });

    //Hasta aquí los datos van bien
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Agrupaciones, Formatting.Indented);

    //Al retornar la data aparece el string con diagonales inversas
    return result;
}
```

Al verificar el contenido de la variable result dandole clic en la lupa, el contenido es:

```
[{
    "Cliente": 2,
    "IdCliente": "Pruebas",
    "Grupos": [{
            "IdGrupo": 1,
            "Grupo": "Pruebas 1",
            "Subgrupos": [{
                "IdSubgrupo": 1,
                "Subgrupo": "Contenido"
            }]
        },
        {
            "IdGrupo": 2,
            "Grupo": "Pruebas 2",
            "Subgrupos": [{
                "IdSubgrupo": 3,
                "Subgrupo": "Sub contenido"
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Pero al retornar el json se convierte a:

```
"[\r\n  {\r\n    \"Cliente\": 2,\r\n    \"IdCliente\": \"Pruebas\",\r\n    \"Grupos\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"IdGrupo\": 1,\r\n        \"Grupo\": \"Pruebas 1\",\r\n        \"Subgrupos\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"IdSubgrupo\": 1,\r\n            \"Subgrupo\": \"Contenido\"\r\n          },\r\n      {\r\n        \"IdGrupo\": 2,\r\n        \"Grupo\": \"Pruebas 2\",\r\n        \"Subgrupos\": [\r\n          {\r\n            \"IdSubgrupo\": 3,\r\n            \"Subgrupo\": \"Sub contenido\"\r\n          }, ]\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n]"
```

Por favor me pueden decir cual es la forma correcta de retornar el json como objeto y no como string, o decirme en que estoy mal. Gracias

Comment: Primero, intenta remover el `Formatting.Indented`, puede que sea eso lo que te está añadiendo el `carriage return y new line (\r\n)`. Estás utilizando el JsonConverter de Newtonsoft? Te invito a utilizar las herramientas que provee .net en su [namespace System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `JSON` está bien formado. Los diagonales inversos `\` son carácter de escape y van a estar presentes en un `JSON` en la mayoría de las ocasiones.

- `\r` es el carácter de **retorno de carro**
- `\n` es el carácter de **nueva linea**. lo equivalente a un ***enter***
- `\"` escapa la comilla doble. De no escapar esta, se interpretaría que el `JSON` termina a la primer aparición de este carácter.

Un `JSON` es un formato de texto, osea, es un `string` y para manipular la información de este como un arreglo o de alguna otra forma, es necesario hacer uso de alguna función o método que lo convierta al formato deseado.
En el caso de `.NET`, y con la misma librería de la que haces uso, tienes el método `DeserealizeObject()`